# Is Jesus God, as well as the son of God in LDS?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, christology

I have not yet been able to find the answer to this question, about LDS Mormon beliefs. I think, because Mormon belief is different from orthodox / mainstream Christianity, that this question provokes anxiety and anger, and is not wanted among Mormons.

> The Question: Do Mormons consider Jesus to be God, as the Father is God and as the Holy Spirit is God?

Comment: God is a term that's a bit overloaded. It's a title (lowercase "god"), but can also refer to a person (capitalized "God"), or even the single divine purpose under which all 3 beings are united. So yes, Jesus can be called God. In LDS theology, the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost are 3 separate, distinct beings, and each one is a god, being a member of the godhead.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and not only is it a severe misunderstanding of pretty much all of our doctrine to think we believe otherwise, but there are also so many scriptures that could be cited in this regard, that one answer probably can't cover all of this question.

I try to use the most clear scriptures I can find. Obviously there are many New Testament scriptures that could be used, as well as from the Book of Mormon, but nevertheless I choose these:

Doctrine and Covenants 14:9

> 9 Behold, I am Jesus Christ, the Son of the living God, who created
>   the heavens and the earth, a light which cannot be hid in darkness;

Doctrine and Covenants 19:1-4

> 1 I am Alpha and Omega, Christ the Lord; yea, even I am he, the
>   beginning and the end, the Redeemer of the world.
>
> 2 I, having accomplished and finished the will of him whose I am,
>   even the Father, concerning me—having done this that I might subdue
>   all things unto myself—
>
> 3 Retaining all power, even to the destroying of Satan and his works
>   at the end of the world, and the last great day of judgment, which I
>   shall pass upon the inhabitants thereof, judging every man according
>   to his works and the deeds which he hath done.
>
> 4 And surely every man must repent or suffer, for I, God, am endless.

---

Answer above, clean-up of confusion (or confusion itself) below.

It should also be stated that we don't believe in a trinity. Rather, The Father is God, the Son is God and the Holy Ghost is God (and they are distinct beings). Together they are what we call the Godhead, each having their role, but all being united in purpose. The Son worships the Father, as manifested in scripture more than enough, and so should we. The Son is subject to the Father, and we are subject to them. Eventually, we shall be heirs to the Father, rising as Jesus has, being joint heirs with Christ.

Romans 8:16-17

> 16 The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the
>   children of God:
>
> 17 And if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with
>   Christ; if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also
>   glorified together.

There is no diminuitive to the title "God", there is no "lesser God". Jesus is God.

Answer (score 0):

For LDS Jesus is not lesser in divinity than the Father because just as a human father can begat a human son, LDS believe our Father in heaven begat Christ in similar fashion but spiritually. Christ is the Son of God but He is not the only son. LDS believe Lucifer is His brother and the rest of mankind were once God's divine children before being sent on Earth to live an earthly life.